# Swift UIStackView - Dynamic View Heights large spacing between cell programmatically

Tags: swift, uistackview

[image]

I am working with a UIStackView programmatically, to dynamically insert a form at a given position. A button is pressed and a UIView is inserted into 0 positions. When the user clicks save on the form, the constraints are wiped, cell removed then replaced with a display UIView. The replacement UIView can be of variable height based upon the amount of text logged from inside the form.

The problem I am having is when the first cell has long text and the second cell has short text entered, the two cells are not flush. This does not occur if the heights are the same. So if the first cell is equal in height to the second, all three cells will appear flush at the top.

The above diagram displays my issue and what I am hoping to accomplish. How do I fix this?

Additionally, I am seeing the below output in regards to my constraints:

```
LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028ac80 MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b74b360.height == 166   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100002870d0 MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b678da0.height == 166   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028db10 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fdf4e8012d0.top == MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b74b360.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000289d80 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b678da0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fdf4e8012d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000028a820 'UISV-spacing' V:[MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b74b360]-(15)-[MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b678da0]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61800009acc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIStackView:0x7fdf4e8012d0.height == 770   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6100002870d0 MyApp.StepView:0x7fdf4b678da0.height == 166   (active)>
```

This is a pretty custom design, nothing like your typical mobile layout. I am wondering if I would be better off just ditching the UIStackView and using constraints. I thought UIStackView since I want to be able to add/remove elements with the sizing correcting itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the desired result by measuring all of the cells within the stackview. If the value was less than 500 I pushed a blank cell into the top of the stack. This ensured all the other cells would appear to align.

Since I was basically rebuilding the StackView each time anyways, this approach made the most sense.